# Is there a way to get title of a google drive file in python using its google drive file id?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I have google drive IDs of many files which I want to download.
However the apis to download google drive files want the filename as well to save the file with that name.

Is there a way in python to get the title/name of the file from the google drive file ID in python?

If so please help to share a sample code.

Comment: please edit your question and include your code download does not require a file name just the id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [file.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) method to download a file does not require a file name it simply requires that you send it the file id.

```
# Call the Drive v3 API
# get the file media data
request = service.files().get_media(fileId=FILEID)

fh = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    print("Download %d%%" % int(status.progress() * 100))
```

What does require a name is when you want to save it to your system.

```
# The file has been downloaded into RAM, now save it in a file
fh.seek(0)
with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
    shutil.copyfileobj(fh, f, length=131072)
```

You can just do a [file.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) to get the metadata of the file first then you can use that when you want to save your file.

```
# Call the Drive v3 API
# Get file name, so we can save it as the same with the same name.
file = service.files().get(fileId=FILEID).execute()
file_name = file.get("name")
print(f'File name is: {file_name}')
```